# reduce camera/photo library image file size for less than 100 KB in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, image, uiimage, image-size

I want to reduce image file size that take from `UIImagePickerController` . I use this method

> NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1);

but it reduce 2.2 MB image file size to 300 KB 
I want my image file size become less than 100 KB.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313428/reduce-image-bytes-size-with-cocoa


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313428/reduce-image-bytes-size-with-cocoa

Comment: After all I found this solution is the best one 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612131/whats-the-easiest-way-to-resize-optimize-an-image-size-with-the-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to reduce image size in kilos is to reduce the size in pixels! Scale it smaller:

```
CGFloat scaleSize = 0.2f;
UIImage *smallImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage
                      scale:scaleSize
                      orientation:image.imageOrientation];
```

Comment: Exactlly! A large image can't be downsized to 100K in jpeg format, even at highest compression level, so idea is to resize it, then compress it.

Comment: @Lefteris  I use this method and instead of 0.2 for scalesize I set it 5 to reduce image size 5 times and then use the previous method but the file size didn't change.

Comment: Scale 1 (one) means same size as original image. You should use a value smaller than one, not bigger.

Comment: this method returns exactly the same image but with a different density maintaining the same file size

Answer (score 8):

Apple's docs state:

> The quality of the resulting JPEG image, expressed as a value from 0.0
>   to 1.0. The value 0.0 represents the maximum compression (or lowest
>   quality) while the value 1.0 represents the least compression (or best
>   quality).

And since the compression quality is a CGFloat, it supports decimal places beyond the tenths place. That being said, try:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.032);
```

Comment: it's not reduce than 300 kb

Answer (score 1):

First resize the image with below method:

```
- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image newSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

call this by:

```
UIImage *newImage=yourImage;
CGSize size=CGSizeMake(newImage.size.width/8,newImage.size.height/8);
newImage=[self resizeImage:newImage newSize:size];
```

And finally compressed your image as required:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 0.5);
NSLog(@"Size of image = %lu KB",(imageData.length/1024));
```